# ModelAndView null in Interceptor when Exception mapped from SimpleMappingExceptionResolver

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, exception, interceptor

Ok, so I'm on a project where we are using spring, and as far as I can tell when a runtime exception is raised and handled by the SimpleMappingExceptionResolver, then when our registered interceptor's postHandle method is called then it's with an empty model and view.

I don't know much about how spring MVC hangs together, but I thought that the SimpleMappingExceptionResolver mapped atype of exception to a ModelAndView. And that this ModelAndView object which would be available for the interceptor to stuff things into the model. If this is not the case, feel free to tell me why, if it is, why am I seeing the null ModelAndView in my interceptor?

Cheers, Chris.

Comment: postHandle method is called after successful handler.handle call. postHandle is not called in case where handler raise exception. In this case only afterCompletion interceptor method will be called after exception resolver call. I have no idea how you get your postHandle called in case where exception raised.

Comment: also if you look into org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet#doDispatch sources, it is easy to understand how interceptors/resolvers works

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure we have the same case or not, but for my case when the system failed to resolve View because ModelAndView is null, I want to show a page that informing about "404 request not found". Initially I tried to use SimpleMappingExceptionResolver and put in the map for viewNames of "404 request not found" (the viewNames calles "/404NotFound"). But I can't find the correct exception.

Finally, what I did to solve my case is by modifying web.xml and put this:

```
    <error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/404NotFound</location>
    </error-page>
```

And since we don't need any controllers to process 404NotFound (just render it as it is), I put this code in application context for mvc.

```
    <mvc:view-controller path="/404NotFound"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm expanding @masted's comment. Really Interceptor isn't called, when request is processed by  ExceptionResolver and according to [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/HandlerInterceptor.html#afterCompletion%28javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,%20javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse,%20java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Exception%29) the `HanlerInterceptor#afterCompletion` method is called after view renderring, so it doesn't help us either.

My solution to this was to create my own **ExceptionHandler** which extends `AbstractHandlerMethodExceptionResolver` and autowires my interceptor. Then after setting view name to my `ModelAndView` and after putting exception there, i call my interceptor's `postHandle()` method.

It is relatively clean and only way i got it working.